# Positioning works good only in debug mode

Tags: css, html

I'm working on designing a page. My expected result is to place an arrow kind of thing bottom of div like [image]

[image]
HTML code :
       `<b aria-hidden="true" role="presentation" id="barrow" tabindex="-1"><bdo></bdo></b>`

CSS code :
           `{
           #barrow{border: 5px solid #585858;
           border-top: 15px  solid #E1B531;
           position: absolute;
           bottom: 68px;
           border-bottom: 0;
           margin-left: 61px;
           }`

The issue is it is not perfectly places in the place i've mentioned. I included the "#tag b" inside div1. When i launch the code, arrow placed in far down from my div1.
But if i go for "Inspect Element", it displays in exact position.....

Why the one works good in debug but not in normal..???????

I've put my head in this for few hours.....don;t know what to do.....
Please help me guys to out of it....

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Vino

Comment: can you share a fiddle with the issue visible? Anyway have you tried to style a pseudoelement instead of using an empty element?

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem with as little code as possible? This will help us solve the problem. You can use a site like [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [jsbin.com](http://jsbin.com/) to show your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly - I would recommend using something like this for that arrow - http://www.cssarrowplease.com/

It will generate the code for you and remove any error that you are having.

Like so:

```
.arrow_box {
position: relative;
background: #88b7d5;
border: 4px solid #c2e1f5;
}
.arrow_box:after, .arrow_box:before {
top: 100%;
left: 50%;
border: solid transparent;
content: " ";
height: 0;
width: 0;
position: absolute;
pointer-events: none;
}
.arrow_box:after {
border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
border-top-color: #88b7d5;
border-width: 30px;
margin-left: -30px;
}
.arrow_box:before {
border-color: rgba(194, 225, 245, 0);
border-top-color: #c2e1f5;
border-width: 36px;
margin-left: -36px;
}
```